# Pass form input value to method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling with a situation where I need to grab the value of an input field to make an API call.

So What I have is this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchWeather = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Zeist&appid=MYID')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); 
    });
    console.log();
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit = {fetchWeather}>
                    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Your city' ref="city"></input>
                    <input type = 'submit' placeholder='Submit' value = 'Submit'></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

A form that runs a function on submit, I used `preventDefault` to stop the page from loading.

The function runs and the page doesn't reload. Now I'd like to grab the text from the input field and log it in that function. The reason why I want this is so I can use it in my API call as a query parameter. I tried many things. I tried logging `e` to see what is inside. It's a very big object and I couldn't find the value I'm looking for. I tried using `ref`, this didn't work either. Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Comment: go through uncontrolled components from react official doc first. https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: I recommend using controlled components in this case, you can then define state for your component and store the value of your input using `value=` and `onChange=` on the ipunt. That way, you'll be able to define `fetchWeather` as a method inside your component and have access to the state object there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

You need to move your `fetchWeather` function inside of your component,

```
export default class App extends Component {
    fetchWeather = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.refs.city.value)//You will get vlue here
      axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Zeist&appid=MYID')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); 
      });
      console.log();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit = {this.fetchWeather}> //refer your function using `this`
                    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Your city' ref="city"></input>
                    <input type = 'submit' placeholder='Submit' value = 'Submit'></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Better way is, using `state`. This is called [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state={
       city: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }
    fetchWeather = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.state.city)//You will get vlue here
      axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Zeist&appid=MYID')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); 
      });
      console.log();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit = {this.fetchWeather}> //refer your function using `this`
                    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Your city' name="city" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleChange} ></input>
                    <input type = 'submit' placeholder='Submit' value = 'Submit'></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a controlled component: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.

I simulated the fetch operation in the snippet.

```js
const fetchWeather = function (data) {
  // simulating fetch
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('GETTING DATA ' + JSON.stringify(data))
  }, 500)
}

// Controlled Component: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      city: ''
    }

    this._handleInputChange = this._handleInputChange.bind(this)
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  _handleInputChange (event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }
  
  _handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    fetchWeather(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    const { city } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='city'
            placeholder='Your city'
            value={city}
            onChange={this._handleInputChange}
          />
          <input type='submit' placeholder='Submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```